# Different ways to check if Http request is from Mobile

Tags: http, mobile

What are the different ways to check if a request is coming from mobile?
I know we can use UserAgent, but is there any other method also?
For eg. cnet.com gives non mobile website even if I pass Mobile Useragent.How are they doing that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS media queries to allow your page to adapt to the dimensions of the display on the device that is rendering the page.  Example: http://getbootstrap.com/

You can use JavaScript with CSS to adjust the display based on the device.  Example: http://modernizr.com/

And, as you mentioned, UserAgent - Example: http://detectmobilebrowsers.mobi/

Comment: But how CNET is doing.They are not doing using media queries or useragent.Since, when I am opening the website on chrome emulator, it is still showing desktop version.

Comment: What are you using for a mobile user agent string?

Comment: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 8_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.3 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0 Mobile/12A4345d Safari/600.1.4